# env-entry outside web.xml?

Tags: java, web.xml

Is there some possibility to define an "env-entry" outside web.xml?. Maybe on a .txt file? or .xml file?

Even better if I could define it outside the project, in a Windows directory.

Answer (score 0):

you may define it in context.xml or server.xml

see [this link](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.EnvEntry) for details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is possible to use a custome xml file maded by me, I don't know, something like configuration.xml in c:\config_folder??

Comment: if you want to define custom environment variables - why not to use java.util.Properties from file?

Comment: Because I have 3 JDBC.properties files in 3 different folders. So I use it an env-entry to define what file use according to the environment (Dev, Test or Demo). But in some cases I don't have a web proyect, so i don't have a web.xml. So it would be really good can define the env-entry in my xml file outside the project

Comment: This is tomcat specific.